# Issue with CSS transitions in Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my web application, I want to animate switching between two elements. The old element should disappear by sliding off to the left and fading out at the same time, after which the new element appears by sliding in from the right while fading in.

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtKaz/8/

I am trying to use CSS transitions for the animation. Everything works fine on first iteration, however once an element has been hidden once, the transition for the appearing element stops working: the appearing element just snaps in, without any motion or fading.

I am experiencing this problem in Chrome, Opera Next and Firefox, but **not** in IE10. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in all browsers but IE (a most bizarre notion)?

The issue seems to be related to `show()`/`hide()`, since there is no problem if I set the elements to `position: absolute` and remove the `show()`/`hide()` calls.

JavaScript:

```
var currentDiv = "div2";

$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var newDiv = currentDiv == 'div1' ? 'div2' : 'div1';
        var oldDiv = currentDiv;

        // Start transition for the disappearing div
        $('#' + oldDiv).css({ opacity: 0, left: -100 });

        // Prepare the new div for showing by first moving it to the right
        // There will be a transition here as well, but it won't be visible
        $('#' + newDiv).css({ opacity: 0, left: +100 });

        setTimeout(function(){
            // Once the transition is done, hide the div so it doesn't occupy space
            $('#' + oldDiv).hide();
            // Show the new div and immediately start its appearing transition
            $('#' + newDiv).show().css({ opacity: 1, left: 0 });
        }, 1000);

        currentDiv = newDiv;
    });    
});
```

CSS:

```
.myDiv {
    position:relative;
    transition: left 1s, opacity 1s;
    width: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="myDiv" style="display:none">
    hello, this is some text
</div>
<div id="div2" class="myDiv" style="display:none">
    and here is some more text
</div>
```

Comment: you might switch from a class to another or add/refresh the transition CSS rule in jQuery ..css() ... px unit is missing within the rule as well ?

Comment: Also there are issues when animating Elements that start off with display: none;
Try to show the element first and animate it after that

Comment: @GCyrillus Yes, I have thought about switching between classes, haven't tried it yet. However, I would like to understand if there is something fundamentally wrong with what I am doing above?

Comment: @Haroldchen Thanks for the info, but isn't that what I'm doing here: `$('#' + newDiv).show().css({ opacity: 1, left: 0 });`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mtKaz/9/ with px units and quotes around css rules/values it works

Comment: @Jaan Almost. You are triggering sequentially, but you are not waiting for the callback. Show() offers a complete callback, where you can add the animation. check the docs for more info http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: @GCyrillus Thanks for your help, but unfortunately you fiddle does something completely different from what I am trying to achieve and doesn't seem to solve the transition problem.

Comment: @Haroldchen Thank you very much! That solved my issue. I actually know about the callbacks, but I didn't think they would be necessary when the show is immediate. I suppose that IE treats immediate show() in a blocking manner as opposed to the other browsers. Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mtKaz/10/

Comment: @Haroldchen If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues with animating elements, which start with the attribute display: none. 
Wait for the complete callback of show() and then set the css properties.

```
$('#' + newDiv).show(400, function(){
$(this).css({ opacity: 1, left: 0 });
});
```

See documentation for details: http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-duration-complete